# Use regex string stored in mysql field for Rails project

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, regex

In order to clean up code for my Rails project, I moved all regex strings to MySQL.  How can I add the string located in MySQL fields to my match method?  Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
foobar = []
regular_ex = StringDb.pluck(:id, :regex) 
# :regex is a column that stores regex strings, ie. '/[a-c]|[1,2,3]/'
regular_ex.each do |exp|
    if foo.match(exp[1])
        foobar << exp[0]
```

Please let me know if my question is not clear.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new regex from string like this

```
Regexp.new str
```

Or using the regex interpolation

```
%r{#{regex_string}}
```

That would mean that you would do something similiar to this

```
foobar = []
regular_ex = StringDb.pluck(:id, :regex) 
# :regex is a column that stores regex strings, ie. '/[a-c]|[1,2,3]/'
regular_ex.each do |exp|
    if Regexp.new(exp).match("stringToMatch")
        # do something
```

Please note two things.

1. In order for this to work you should remove the starting and trailing  slash from the regex in database.

Store '[a-c]|[1,2,3]' instead of '/[a-c]|[1,2,3]/'.

2. I'm not really sure why you decided to store all regexes in the database but it does not sound like a good idea.

Comment: Hi Dabrorius, all the regex strings already exist and are located in my MySQL db (StringDb).  My question is how can I actually use the regex strings in my db for my foo.match regex.  For example, let's say that exp[1] from my code snippet is a string = '/[a-c]|[1,2,3]/' in my db.  I'm trying to get that string into my regex.  ie.  foo.match(/[a-c]|[1,2,3]/)

Comment: You should use it the other way around. You should call match on regex and then pass it in the string. /[a-c]|[1,2,3]/.match(foo) So foo should be a string and you should call match on a regex.

Comment: Thanks Dabrorius.  Your suggestion to use Regexp.new(exp[1]).match("stringToMatch") worked.  I'm still not sure why my way doesn't work but I'm sure it's in the regex/match documention. As for why I moved all my regular expression strings to a MySQL db, it saved me about 300 lines of code in my Rails app for the 100 or so different regex strings I had.  (DRY madness on my part)